# How to restrict our domain so that no one can do CNAME of our domain?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53, dnsmasq, reverse-dns

I want to restrict my domain so that no one can do CNAME of my domain.

Suppose, I have my domain(**example.com**) and someone has another domain(**xyz.com**).

There is a game application running on example.com.

Nothing is running on xyz.com.

Someone has done CNAME of his domain(**xyz.com**) to my domain(**example.com**).Now the xyz.com is pointing to my game application.

How I can **restrict** people using my domain and I want to restrict it on

**a) DNS level**

**b) Server level**

Please help me to sort it out?

Answer (score 3):

Everyone will always be able to create CNAME pointing to your domain. That's something you can't prevent.

On the server level you can check (in `.htaccess` for example in Apache) which domain is requested and if it does not match yours, redirect the request somewhere else:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !example.com$
RewriteRule . http://redirect.page.com [R=301,L]
```

In Nginx:

```
if ($host != 'example.com') {
  rewrite . http://redirect.page.com permanent;
}
```

You should also configure [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) so assets like scripts, stylesheets and images load for your domain only.

Comment: You don't really need this explicit check, you just need to configure a named (virtual) server for your domain, and all requests not matching that domain simply result in a 404.

Comment: Apache will actually serve the first VirtualHost in case any ServerName or ServerAlias is not matched